# Can a pointer to heap be discerned from static and automatic addresses?

Tags: c, pointers, static, heap-memory, elf

Consider:

```c
static void
classifyPointer(const void *p)
{
    ....
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     const char *p1 = "Meow";
     char        p2[3];
     char       *p3 = malloc(11);

     classifyPointer(p1);    /* string literal */
     classifyPointer(p2);    /* stack */
     classifyPointer(p3);    /* heap */
     classifyPointer(main);  /* function */

     return 0;
}
```

Can such a `classifyPointer` function -- able to classify addresses passed to it -- be implemented? Just to print the kind of memory pointed at by the argument?

I am fully aware, that there is no *standard* method, that's guaranteed to work everywhere.

But I suspect, there exist large enough group(s) of platforms (such as ELF-using Unixes, or wherever jemalloc is used), where this is possible -- at least, for *some* of the memory-classes.

And, if it is possible, some useful optimizations may become worthwhile on those platforms... For example, various objects (like `Tcl_Obj` and equivalents in other interpreters) make private copies of fields during construction -- allocating memory, copying the data over, freeing the memory later -- which is all unnecessary, when the constructor's arguments are *read-only* string literals.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [Union](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm), though it's unclear from your description exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Certainly not in any portable or robust way.  For instance, given the existence of shared libraries and other DSOs, static data might be all over the address space.  Likewise with stack, given that each thread has its own.  Parsing `/proc/self/maps` on Linux *might* give you some idea, but I doubt you want that kind of overhead.

Comment: Sidenote: if you want to get rid of unnecessary copies, you may be better off carefully using `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` where no ownership is necessary. Or not.

Comment: Normally you'd instead design an API where the caller passes information about the lifetime of the object, if it's needed (e.g. a flag indicating that the string has static storage duration and will remain unchanged).  Some languages like Rust have this kind of thing built in.  But this is C, and so as with most other advanced stuff, if you want it, you have to build it, and it won't be pretty.

Comment: I may be Ok with missing _some_ optimization opportunities, if I can quickly detect _most_ of them. The linked-to question has an answer showing, how to use `etext`, `edata`, etc. Would that still work in 2021?

Comment: @MikhailT. The linked-to answer was written and tested by me in August of this year, so: Yes.  (On Linux, at least.)

Comment: What about using `-lelf` -- are there any APIs there, that can be used instead of the Linux-only parsing of `/proc/self/maps`?